# if i am on a node page how can i get one of the taxonomy terms for that node?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

In drupal 8, if I am on a certain page, how can I get the taxonomy terms for one particular taxonomy that that node has ?  I want to do this in a custom module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had to do it in three steps , not sure if there is an easier way:

```
$taxonomy=$node->field_taxonomy;
$taxonomy_value=$taxonomy->getValue();
$tid=$channel_value[0]['target_id'];
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to access it via its field:

`$node->field_taxonomy->value`

Comment: Nope, not value, either target_id for the ID or ->entity for the term entity. Also, worth noting that the field name is whatever you named it, terms are not structured in vocabularies on nodes but based on the fields you put them in, like anything else too

Comment: for the field taxonomy I get an object but can't get the value with ->value

Comment: [field_pup_channel] => Array
                (
                    [x-default] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [target_id] => 2041
                                )

                        )

                )